# Singular or plural for multiple subjects?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, grammatical-number

Which is more correct to say:

- Five and four **are** eight
- Five and four **is** eight

My Logic teacher has sent this to us to figure out.  What is written above is all the information we were given.  I know that in terms of **math** neither is correct.

I have tried to disregard that the words are numbers and think about in in a different way.  I do not know the rules for the correct use of *are* and *is* in the English language.  If you can help that would be great.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is apparently about formal logic, not English.

Comment: The English issue is covered elsewhere. The philosophical question (of whether the two items *four* and *five* should be considered as a single entity of the total, two entities as the consitituents of the total or nine entities as the complete set) is out of scope.

Comment: Using the first one would get you two weeks in prison if the maths police caught you. Using the second one, fourteen days. The grammar police would let them do the paperwork.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring, as you said, the use of *and* with numbers, and sticking with *and* as a logical connective, the sentence is presumably to be considered as *X AND Y (is|are) Z*, where you are to choose *is* or *are*. The answer is *is*, because the truth value *Z* is singular - it is *true* or *false* (or something else in, say, a 3-valued logic).

But at that level this is not an English question but a logic question, so it should be closed as off-topic, IMO.

Comment: So, “Peter and Paul is a pair” then?

Comment: @tchrist: No, that doesn't use *and* as a logical connective. It is the context here (of a Locic class assignment) that suggests the interpretation I made (see "*presumably*").